# Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu not run in IE11 cssVars(): variable "--bs-gutter-x" is undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown, angular10

i hope you can help me. I am triying to implement at simple dropdown menu using bootstrap 5 in IE 11, but i have a problem, the component not run in IE11.
The errors i have in console are:

```
cssVars(): variable "--bs-gutter-x" is undefined
cssVars(): variable "--bs-gutter-y" is undefined
cssVars(): variable "--bs-table-bg" is undefined
cssVars(): variable "--bs-table-striped-color" is undefined
```

thanks your for all help.

Comment: I thought BS5 did not support/has limited support for IE - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Comment: Thanks , you have reason , Bootstrap 5  not support  IE <=11 versions.